# How to add Script as Field's value?

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to add this script:

```
<script language="javascript"> document.write('' + geoip_city() +''); </script>
```

As the field's value and as to the onfocus, so it erases it on click.

```
<input type="text" name="question" value="" style="display:none" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Agregá tu ciudad') {this.value=''}">
```

How do I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<input type="text" name="question" value="'+geoip_city()+'" style="display:none" onfocus="if (this.value == \''+geoip_city()+'\') {this.value=\'\'}">');
</script>
```

This simply prints the whole input through javascript (not nice to read at all, but fulfills the purpose).
the default value is the value return by `geoip_city`. If you click the element the default value will be deleted.
I hope I understood you correctly, feel free to provide additional information if this isn't what you're looking for.